# How can I bind the value of an option that its loaded thru a list

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

What I'm trying to achieve is after loading the option control (drop-down list) with all the months, I need to bind the selected value to a Dto value (@bind="@ClientDto.WaitingPeriodMonths")

So technically trying to achieve this result but with the drop-down list
<input asp-for="WaitingPeriodMonths" class="form-control" @bind="@ClientDto.WaitingPeriodMonths"

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <Select id="monthdropdown" class="form-control" @onchange="@MonthClicked">
      <option style="font-weight:bold" value="">-- Months --</option>
      @if (@Months != null)
      {
         @foreach (var month in @Months)
         {
             <option value="@month">@month</option>
         }
      }
 </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with binding in selects is that you'll run into Type conversion if you simply try to bind non primitives.

```
<select @bind="@SelectedFoo">
  @foreach (var foo in FooList)
    {
      <option value="@foo">@foo</option>      
    }
</select>

@code
{
   List<Foo> FooList = new List<Foo>();
   Foo SelectedFoo {get; set;}
}
```

This will throw an exception of:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type
> 'Foo' does not have an associated
> TypeConverter that supports conversion from a string. Apply
> 'TypeConverterAttribute' to the type to register a converter.'

You can either look into implementing that, or bind it to an ID like value of Foo instead.

```
<select @bind="@FooID">
  @foreach (var foo in FooList)
    {
      <option value="@foo.ID">@foo.ID @foo.Name</option>
    }
</select>

@code
{
   List<Foo> FooList = new List<Foo>();
   string FooID {get; set;}
}
```

To get back to your SelectedFoo, you can simply change the setter of your FooID to also find the associated value in your list again and set SelectedFoo, i.e. through LINQ.

```
<select @bind="@FooID">
  @foreach (var foo in FooList)
    {
      if (FooID = foo.ID)
      {
        <option value="@foo.Id" selected>@foo.id @foo.Name</option>
      }
      else
      {
         <option value="@foo.Id">@foo.Id @foo.Name</option>
      }
    }
</select>

@code
{
   private string _fooID;
   private List<Foo> FooList = new List<Foo>();

   public Foo SelectedFoo {get; set;}
   public string FooID 
   {
     get {return _fooID;} 
     set
     {
       _fooID = value;
       SelectedFoo = FooList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == value);
     }
   }
}
```

Ofcourse if your attribute is already a primitive, you don't need this hassle. And only need a variable of your primitive type to bind it to.